# rails 3 not working with windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

ruby 1.8.7
gem 1.3.7
rails 3.0.0, 3.0.0.rc

when i write rails -v
error message come

**Could not find gem 'mysql2 <>=0, runtime>' in any of the gem sources.**
Try running 'bundle install'.

when I run bundle install then also it cann't install mysql2

please help me.

Answer (score 5):

The `mysql2` gem does not currently support Windows (although [I hear they are working on it](http://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues#issue/8)). Just use the old `mysql` gem for now.

To be specific:

1. Put this line in your Gemfile:

   `gem 'mysql', '2.8.1'`
2. Run `bundle install`
3. Make sure you use `adapter: mysql` and *not* `adapter: mysql2` in your `database.yml`.

This is how my system is currently set up, and it works fine with Rails 3.0.0.

Comment: To note, you will need to replace `mysql2` with `mysql` in your `database.yml` file.

Answer (score 3):

This error can be handled now. No need to change mysql2 to mysql in Gemfile and 
database.yml. You can install mysql2 gem on windows by following the steps 
given in post - http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-192-and.html

Comment: What about using the mysql server from wamp? I dnt find the opt folder in my mysql folder. Mysql 5.5.16. When i do >gem install mysql2, it says mysql2 gem installed successfully. Not sure what i am missing :(